# Duplicate answers deleted, now I can't restore any of them

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I posted a good answer (about an update of the matter) to a few similar questions, all asking essentially the same.

All of my comments were deleted and the mod commented:

> Please don't post duplicate answers. If the questions are the same, pick the best one to answer and then flag the other(s) as duplicates. If they're not the same, then tailor your answer to the specifics of each question.

Which makes total sense. But now I can't pick the best one and post it there, because it says the answer is a duplicate of my original answer, and I can't undelete the original answer because it was deleted by a moderator.

What should I do?

Comment: Only mods can reverse mod deletions.  Link to the question which you think is the best one to use as a dupe target so that the answer can be restored.

Comment: Custom flagging is the way to go in this case, posting to Meta is only really helpful when you need to discuss it or if there's something non-moderators can do about it.

Comment: Side note: if you posted *comments* as *answers* it would be the best if they stay deleted... Otherwise it is not clear why you can't see deleted *answers*...

Comment: Hey, thank you all. @DanisFiddlingbyFirelight - here's the answer I'd like to undelete: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59682983/2588319 , thanks!

Comment: *posting to Meta is only really helpful when you need to discuss it* -- well, @JohnMontgomery seeing as the favored course of action is unclear, discussion becomes necessary.  If the website were clearer, then discussion wouldn't be necessary.  I'm having this problem today, and I see it was discussed 3.5 years ago and the website hasn't been modified to be self-explanatory (e.g.: you appear to be posting duplicate answers, which isn't allowed.  If there are duplicate questions, answer one and flag the rest as duplicates) so I imagine the need for discussion will continue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I posted a good answer (about an update of the matter) to a few similar questions, all asking essentially the same.

We get a lot of those copy/paste. People search questions that they can answer, and paste the exact same answer. Does that really improve quality of the site? No it doesn't, it just adds to the noise (specially when the questions already have valid answers).

> All of my comments were deleted and the mod commented

You were lucky to get a comment explaining why the answer was deleted. We get so many duplicate answers that I tend to delete them without explanation. Curiously we rarely get complaints about that.

If you can paste the exact same answer to several questions, most of those questions should have been closed as duplicates then. You can flag as such, picking the best question. Post an answer for the best question.

If the questions are slightly different, and you post an adapted answer, even if the answers are similar but adapted to the questions, then you may get a pass.

> I can't undelete the original answer because it was deleted by a moderator.

It's meant that way: as opposed to question closures, moderator deletions only can be undone by moderators, so we can control content. Anyway, if you edit a deleted answer significantly you can custom flag for undeletion. A moderator will review the changes (wait for a few days), and will decide if they're significant enough to undelete the answer.

What we can also do, is to ask us change the undeleted answer by another one that you'd prefer. In general, I try to keep the answer where there are upvotes, but when all answers have the same score, we just delete all but one.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and reasonable response! I appreciate it.

Comment: *Curiously we rarely get complaints about that.* -- I've spent 90 minutes trying to figure out how to reach the moderator that gave me this rejection notice and it appears to be impossible.  So, I'm not sure how you WOULD get complaints about it?  I wasn't even looking to complain, just understand/clarify how I should proceed.

Comment: You don't need to speak with the moderator that took action to learn how to proceed.

Comment: *We get so many duplicate answers that I tend to delete them without explanation* -- If it's a serious burden, why not automate this case?  I wish I had been presented with a dialog that said: "you are repeating answers.  If the questions are duplicates, just answer the best one, delete any other repeats of your answer, and flag the rest as duplicate."  This would have saved me 90 minutes today and saved you apparently much time as well.

Comment: *You don't need to speak with the moderator that took action to learn how to proceed.* -- @KevinB Thanks, but I've tried to find out how to proceed and in a long discussion on a question that turns out to have duplicated this older question, no-one has told me yet how to comply with Martijn's request that I leave one good answer.

Comment: you have two options, [and both have been presented to you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392819/duplicate-answers-deleted-now-i-cant-restore-any-of-them). Request undeletion of one of them, or move on.